# Set proof attempt

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not very confident in what I'm doing here yet so I'd just like to get some verification that if the logic is correct or not. Thanks.

Prove of disprove:

P(R ∪ S) ⊆ P(R) ∪ P(S) ∪ P(R ∩ S)

My attempt:

```
Counterexample: 

Let R= {1,2} and S= {2,3}

R ∪ S = {1,2,3} and R ∩ S = {2}

Now {1,3} ⊆ R ∪ S = {1,3} ∈ P(R ∪ S)

but {1,3} ∉ P(R) ∪ P(S) ∪ P(R ∩ S)

Since {1,3} ∈ P(R ∪ S) but {1,3} ∉ P(R) ∪ P(S) ∪ P(R ∩ S)

P(R ∪ S) ⊄ P(R) ∪ P(S) ∪ P(R ∩ S)
```

Comment: Your counterexample is fine.

Comment: What is P(.....)?